# How to distribute Mapreduce task in hadoop streaming

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

For example I have multiple lines log file
I have mapper.py. this script do parse file.
In this case I want to do my mapper it independently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop Streaming is already "distributed", but is isolated to one input and output stream. You would need to write a script to loop over the files and run individual streaming jobs per-file.

If you want to batch process many files, then you should upload all files to a single HDFS folder, and then you can use `mrjob` (assuming you actually want MapReduce), or you could switch to `pyspark` to process them all in parallel, since I see no need to do that sequentially.